# R library unwrittable

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

I want to update the core packages of R on ubuntu 12.04. But every time R says that it has no permissions to write to the library. Other packages with do not come with the r-core installation through the terminal. `sudo apt-get install r-base`  are installed in my personal library. I gave myself the owner permissions of every library folder and this does not work.

So am i able to make this library writtable and if so, how can i do it? Or is there a way to Run R as administrator/root.

I already tried a lot of options from the internet but could not find what i was looking for.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you should post this on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by default R packages get installed under `/usr/lib`, and you need superuser privileges to install more.

So you can either run R using sudo and run commands like `install.packages()` from there:

```
sudo R
```

or edit your `~/.Renviron` as described in [this post](http://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/mathstatistics-packages/installing-r-libraries-locally-your-home-directory), e.g.

```
$ mkdir ~/R_libs
```

And add this line to `~/.Renviron`:

```
R_LIBS="/home/your_username/R_libs"
```

Comment: thanks for the hint! it works perfectly, the packages are now updated and can be used.